# Get URL of image Chevereto

Tags: php

Sorry for my english language which is not very good.

I try to link my chevereto images on a homepage of my principal website.

I can rebuilt the image url with the sql when i now the id.

But i want to link to the image page with the infos, embed codes, etc.

The link is like this:

https://www.example.com/chevereto/image/acbR

acbR is not in the database Sql. I think it's a string built with a phpscript.

On the code of the script Chevereto i found this fonction:

```
function chevereto_id($var) {
$base_chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; // DON'T REPEAT A SINGLE CHAR!

for ($n = 0; $n<strlen($base_chars); $n++) {
    $i[] = substr( $base_chars,$n ,1);
}

$passhash = hash('sha256', 'c70a053b');
$passhash = (strlen($passhash) < strlen($base_chars)) ? hash('sha512', 'c70a053b') : $passhash;

for ($n=0; $n < strlen($base_chars); $n++) {
    $p[] =  substr($passhash, $n ,1);
}

array_multisort($p, SORT_DESC, $i);
$base_chars = implode($i);

        $string = '';
        $len = strlen($base_chars);
        while($var >= $len) {
            $mod = bcmod($var, $len);
            $var = bcdiv($var, $len);
            $string = $base_chars[$mod].$string;
        }
        return $base_chars[$var] . $string;

}
```

With id number **84** i have to find **acbR**

but it dont works.

If someone know chevereto script and want to help me, i will be very happy!

Answer (score 2):

Chevereto uses encoded IDs to reference the actual table IDs. Here, check the [source](https://github.com/Chevereto/Chevereto-Free/blob/master/app/lib/functions.php#L444).

You need to use this:

```
CHV\decodeID($encoded_id);
```

(which was just below the code you entered).

Comment: Hi Rodolpho, and thanks for your feedback. I try to thanks you on the chevereto forum, but i can't. So Thank you very much, it works good with your help!!